# R - preparation of pretty comparison file with diffdf

Tags: r, comparison

I am using diffdf function to compare two files. It produces simple file if differences are found or not but I am wondering if there is any way to create in R 'pretty' outputs with title, notes etc? How can I add any title to produced file from diffdf function? For now I am adding it with linux.

Thank you.